# Making equal-sized tabs to fill the full width of a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would you simplify the following block of jQuery code?

I use this in a tab-box to size the tabs to style the tabs to the full width of the box no matter if it's 2 or 10 tabs...

It works perfectly, just interested if there's a better/shorter way to achieve the goal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.tabs-list').each(function () {
    if ($(this).children().length == 2)
  $(this).addClass("two");
    if ($(this).children().length == 3)
  $(this).addClass("three");
    if ($(this).children().length == 4)
  $(this).addClass("four");
    if ($(this).children().length == 5)
  $(this).addClass("five");
    if ($(this).children().length == 6)
  $(this).addClass("six");
    if ($(this).children().length == 7)
  $(this).addClass("seven");
    if ($(this).children().length == 8)
  $(this).addClass("eight");
    if ($(this).children().length == 9)
  $(this).addClass("nine");
    if ($(this).children().length == 10)
  $(this).addClass("ten");
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you adding classes like this to apply CSS?

Comment: @George - Yes, that's how I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [X-Y problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/148099) and, unless you need to target IE ≤ 7, an abuse of jQuery.  If your goal is to completely fill a box with equal-width child elements, there are better ways to do it.  In general, if you are using jQuery to perform a layout task, you're probably doing it wrong.  A pure-CSS solution would be faster, would reflow automatically if the DOM is altered, and would generalize to any number of child elements.  For a collaborative project, keeping all of your presentation logic in CSS would also be the Right Thing To Do: you don't want designers editing your JavaScript code.

[One way](//stackoverflow.com/a/5353082/1157100) is use the `display` property to tell the browser to render the `ul.tabs-list` as a table, and each `li` as a table cell.  To make them all equal width, [set `table-layout: fixed` on the `ul`](//stackoverflow.com/q/20375288/1157100).  This works on [every modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-layout) (notably not IE ≤ 7).

```css
ul {
    width: 400px;
}

ul.tabs-list {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

ul.tabs-list > li {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs-list">
  <li>1 of 1</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tabs-list">
  <li>1 of 3</li>
  <li>2 of 3</li>
  <li>3 of 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tabs-list">
  <li>1 of 10</li>
  <li>2 of 10</li>
  <li>3 of 10</li>
  <li>4 of 10</li>
  <li>5 of 10</li>
  <li>6 of 10</li>
  <li>7 of 10</li>
  <li>8 of 10</li>
  <li>9 of 10</li>
  <li>10 of 10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the length as an index for an array containing classes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var classes = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];
    $('ul.tabs-list').each(function () {
        $(this).addClass(classes[$(this).children().length]);
    });
});
```